# Parse string to int or float with boost spirit

Tags: parsing, floating-point, int, boost-spirit-qi

I need to parse a wstring to int, float or a string itself. I found a question similar to mine [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125582/boost-spirit-qi-numeric-parsing-of-integer-and-floating-points) but I don't understand how to use the parser. I don't find the test_parser method. The question is: after implementing the custom rules for the parser, how to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing a wstring to an int is straight forward:

```
wstring str(L"1234");
int i = 0;
qi::parse(str.begin(), str.end(), qi::int_, i);
assert(i == 1234);
```

Similarily, parsing a float looks like:

```
wstring str(L"1234.567");
double d = 0;
qi::parse(str.begin(), str.end(), qi::double_, d);
assert(d == 1234.567);
```

I'm not sure what you mean by 'parsing a string'. If you mean it as parsing a quoted string you  could write it as:

```
wstring str(L"\"abc\"");
wstring s;
qi::parse(str.begin(), str.end(), '"' >> *~qi::char_('"') >> '"', s);
assert(s == L"abc");
```

the expession `'"' >> *~qi::char_('"') >> '"'` means: a quote (`'"'`) followed by (`>>`) zero or more (`*`) characters which are not a quote (`~qi::char_('"')`) followed by (`>>`) another quote (`'"'`) .