# boost spirit semantic action requirements

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

Given the following actions

```
struct Data {
    double d;
    void operator()( double dd,
                     boost::spirit::qi::unused_type,
                     boost::spirit::qi::unused_type )
    { d = dd; }
};

struct Printer {
    void operator()( double dd,
                     boost::spirit::qi::unused_type,
                     boost::spirit::qi::unused_type ) const
    { std::cout << dd; }
};
```

the code

```
void foo( const std::string &s ) {
    Printer p;
    boost::spirit::qi::parse( s.begin(), s.end(),
                              boost::spirit::qi::double_[ p ] );
}
```

does compile while

```
double foo( const std::string &s ) {
    Data d;
    boost::spirit::qi::parse( s.begin(), s.end(),
                              boost::spirit::qi::double_[ d ] );
    return d.d;
}
```

does not.

Looking at the examples in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/semantic_actions.html, one sees that the function objects use a `operator()` declared `const`. The error message C3848 of MSVC suggests something similar.

Is constness required here? The documentation in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/action.html only says the signature `void( Attrib&, Context, bool& )` is required.

Remark: I must admit I don't really understand the sentence

> The function or function object is expected to return the value to
>   generate output from by assigning it to the first parameter, `attr`.

in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Q.2:** Remark: I must admit I don't really understand the sentence

**A.** You could look at [boost spirit semantic action parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066701/boost-spirit-semantic-action-parameters/3067881#3067881) for indepth explanation of it. Here is the short version:

```
void action_f(std::string& attribute, 
        qi::unused_type const& context, 
        bool& flag)
{
    boost::fusion::at_c<0>(context.attributes) = "hello world"; // return the attribute value
    flag = true; // signal parse success
}
```

---

> **Q.1:** Is constness required here? The documentation in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/action.html only says the signature void( Attrib&, Context, bool& ) is required.

**A.** The const-ness may not be *explicitely* required by the library, however the requirement is *implicitely* introduced by the C++ language <strike>due the way you are using the parser expression</strike><sup>1</sup>:

The expression template

```
boost::spirit::qi::double_[ d ]
```

yields a *temporary*, which when passed to the `qi::parse` API can only get bound to a **`const`** reference<sup>2,3</sup>. This is where the 'const' on the whole parser expresion is introduced, and it extends equally to members of the subexpression(s), such as those that store the *semantic action*, `d`.

Therefore the instance of `d` at the time of deferred invocation will be logically `const` and therefore the `operator()` will not be selected, whereas `operator() const` will.

---

<sup>1.</sup> Upon more thought, it doesn't really depend on how you use it. The logic of my explanation is sound, but because spirit even *supports* inline parser expressions, `call()`-ing parsers is **necessarily** a `const` member operation on that parser, and as such all other operations will be in `const` context anyway. And indeed, in `boost::spirit::traits::action_dispatch::operator()` you'll see the calleables being passed as `F const&`, e.g. reflecting this.

<sup>2.</sup> Spirit V2 does not support move semantics for rules - nor, indeed, does it require them

<sup>3.</sup> The lifetime of the temporary will be extends to the end of the containing full expression, as per standardese