# boost spirit semantic action using non-void function objects

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

In my semantic action I'm not just trying to print out what has been parsed. But the semantic action function is supposed to create some new object which in turn is supposed to be the value created by the parser.

Let's assume the following task:
The parser should get passed the address/reference to an object

```
typedef std::pair<
    std::map<std::string, std::size_t>,
    std::map<std::size_t, std::string>
> mapping;
```

and the parser should convert all non-white-space strings into a `std::size_t` return a `std::vector<std::size_t>` on EOI representing all the strings. Of course this means creating/finding entries in the mapping above.

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_char_class.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
typedef std::pair<
    std::map<std::string, std::size_t>,
    std::map<std::size_t, std::string>
> mapping;

struct convert
{   mapping &m_r;
    convert(mapping &_r)
        :m_r(_r)
    {
    }
    std::size_t operator()(const std::string &_r, const boost::fusion::unused_type&, const boost::fusion::unused_type&) const
    {   const auto pFind = m_r.first.find(_r);
        if (pFind != m_r.first.end())
            return pFind->second;
        else
        {   const auto iID = m_r.first.size();
            m_r.second.insert(std::make_pair(iID, _r));
            m_r.first.insert(std::make_pair(_r, iID));
            return iID;
        }
    }
};
template<typename Iterator>
struct parser:qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<std::size_t>(), ascii::space_type>
{   qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<std::size_t>(), ascii::space_type> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::size_t(), ascii::space_type> name;
    parser(mapping &_r)
        :parser::base_type(start)
    {   name = (+qi::char_)[convert(_r)];
        start %= *name;
    }
};



int main(int, char**)
{   const auto sVector = std::vector<char>(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<char>());
    mapping sMapping;
    parser<std::vector<char>::const_iterator> sParser(sMapping);
    qi::phrase_parse(sVector.begin(), sVector.end(), sParser, ascii::space_type());

}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want the parser to produce is just the sequence of "word ids" (let's call them atoms).

Only the functor that will fuel your semantic action needs to "know about" the mappings.

I'm going to simplify your data-structure a bit here:

```
using AtomId = size_t;
using Atom = std::string_view; // or boost::string_view

struct mapping {
    std::map<Atom, AtomId> by_word;
    std::map<AtomId, Atom> by_id;
};
```

### About That Semantic Action

You can read about the [Anatomy Of Spirit Semantic Actions](http://boost-spirit.com/home/2010/03/03/the-anatomy-of-semantic-actions-in-qi/).

If you want to use the synthesized , local, exposed or inherited attributes, you will have decode the context parameter. Still the best treatment of this is this answer: [boost spirit semantic action parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066701/boost-spirit-semantic-action-parameters/3067881#3067881)

However, if you've looked at it, you'll find it's not very convenient. Instead, I'd suggest to stay in the Phoenix domain (where things like `_1`, `_val`, `_pass`, `_r1` and `_a` magically have the intended meanings, without having to know how to address them in the context).

In that case, you will want your function to be like:

```
struct convert_f {
    mapping &m_ref;

    using Range = boost::iterator_range<It>;

    AtomId operator()(Range const& text) const {
        Atom atom{&*text.begin(), text.size()};
        auto& left  = m_ref.by_word;
        auto& right = m_ref.by_id;

        auto it = left.find(atom);

        if (it != left.end())
            return it->second;
        else {
            const auto iID = left.size();
            left.emplace (atom, iID);
            right.emplace(iID, atom);
            return iID;
        }
    }
};

boost::phoenix::function<convert_f> convert;
```

You could have made `Range` just `std::string`, but I was thinking ahead, and since you read the full file into a vector, you can use a `string_view` based on the raw source iterator range, to avoid copying anything. This also removes the creepy redundancy of storing the same `std::string` inside two maps¹.

¹ *but see the new "Bonus" section*

### Some Varied Problem Points

1. BUG: if you expect `+char_` to match only contiguous chars, make sure you wrap it in a `lexeme[]` (so it cannot skip whitespaces silently) OR of course make the rule implicitly lexeme (see [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)).
2. BUG: don't use `+char_` unless you mean to parse /anything/ In your case, you want contiguous stretches of non-space, so at least make it `+qi::graph`
3. BUG: when reading the data from `std::cin` you already skip whitespace, so all input will become on big word again. Use `std::noskipws` first OR use `std::istreambuf_iterator` instead `std::istream_iterator`. Subtle, I know.
4. don't expose your skipper unless you mean for the caller to change it

I probably forgot some more steps, but for now, let's forget about that and just drop a demo:

### DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/783df869d5ac9822)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <string_view> // or <boost/utility/string_view.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using AtomId = size_t;
using Atom   = std::string_view; // or boost::string_view
using Atoms  = std::vector<AtomId>;

struct mapping {
    std::map<Atom, AtomId> by_word;
    std::map<AtomId, Atom> by_id;
};

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It>
struct parser : qi::grammar<It, Atoms()> {
    parser(mapping &r) : parser::base_type(start), convert({r}) {
        using namespace qi;

        // we don't expose the skipper anymore, so we specify it at toplevel
        start = skip(ascii::space)[ *name ]; 

        name  = raw[ +graph ] [_val = convert(_1)];
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It, Atoms()> start;
    qi::rule<It, AtomId()> name;

    struct convert_f {
        mapping &m_ref;

        using Range = boost::iterator_range<It>;

        AtomId operator()(Range const& text) const {
            Atom atom{&*text.begin(), text.size()};
            auto& left  = m_ref.by_word;
            auto& right = m_ref.by_id;

            auto it = left.find(atom);

            if (it != left.end())
                return it->second;
            else {
                const auto iID = left.size();
                left.emplace (atom, iID);
                right.emplace(iID, atom);
                return iID;
            }
        }
    };

    boost::phoenix::function<convert_f> convert;
};

int main() {
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    std::string const input { std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cin), {} };

    mapping sMapping;
    parser<It> const sParser(sMapping);

    if (qi::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), sParser)) {
        std::cout << "Parsed " << sMapping.by_id.size() << " unique atoms\n";
        for (auto& [atom, id] : sMapping.by_word) {
            std::cout << atom << "(" << id << ")\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Prints (for the [current post text](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74521e576e31ec71/main.cpp)):

```
Parsed 282 unique atoms
!=(153)
"know(34)
"word(19)
##(63)
&m_ref;(135)
(atom,(161)
(it(152)
(let's(21)
(see(230)
(so(220)
(where(111)
**<kbd>[Live(279)
,(78)
//(50)
/anything/(236)
0.(208)
=(46)
About(64)
Action(67)
Actions](http://boost-spirit.com/home/2010/03/03/the-anatomy-of-semantic-actions-in-qi/).(75)
Atom(48)
Atom>(60)
AtomId(45)
AtomId>(57)
BUG:(209)
Coliru]()</kbd>**(281)
DEMO(278)
However,(92)
I(174)
I'd(105)
I'm(37)
If(76)
In(129)
Instead,(104)
OR(225)
Of(73)
On(280)
Only(25)
Phoenix(109)
Points(207)
Problem(206)
Range(136)
Semantic(66)
Some(204)
Spirit(74)
Still(86)
Subtle,(261)
That(65)
There(0)
This(193)
Use(255)
Varied(205)
What(11)
You(68)
[Anatomy(72)
`+char_`(211)
`+qi::graph`(241)
`Range`(171)
`_1`,(114)
`_a`(119)
`_pass`,(116)
`_r1`(117)
`_val`,(115)
`lexeme[]`(219)
`std::cin`(246)
`std::istream_iterator`.(260)
`std::istreambuf_iterator`(258)
`std::noskipws`(256)
`std::string`(200)
`std::string`,(172)
`string_view`(183)
a(40)
about(71)
about"(35)
action(32)
address(127)
again.(254)
ahead,(177)
all(249)
already(247)
also(194)
and(118)
answer:(90)
anything.(192)
at(96)
atom);(164)
atoms).(24)
atom{&*text.begin(),(142)
attribute(9)
attributes,(81)
auto(149)
auto&(144)
avoid(190)
based(184)
be(132)
become(251)
best(87)
big(252)
binding(4)
bit(41)
boost::iterator_range<It>;(137)
boost::phoenix::function<convert_f>(167)
boost::string_view(52)
but(173)
by_id;(61)
by_word;(58)
call(22)
caller(266)
can(69)
cannot(221)
case,(130)
change(267)
chars,(215)
complexity(42)
const(141)
const&(139)
context(84)
context).(128)
contiguous(214)
convenient.(103)
convert;(168)
convert_f(134)
copying(191)
could(169)
course(226)
creepy(196)
data(244)
decode(83)
demo:(277)
domain(110)
don't(232)
drop(276)
else(157)
expect(210)
expose(263)
exposed(8)
file(180)
find(99)
first(257)
for(265)
forget(275)
forgot(269)
from(245)
fuel(29)
full(179)
function(131)
functor(26)
going(38)
have(82)
having(124)
here:(43)
how(126)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965).(231)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066701/boost-spirit-semantic-action-parameters/3067881#3067881(91)
iID(158)
iID);(162)
iID;(165)
ids"(20)
if(93)
implicitly(228)
in(108)
inherited(80)
input(250)
inside(201)
instead(259)
intended(121)
into(181)
is(1)
it(150)
it's(100)
it,(97)
it->second;(156)
iterator(188)
just(16)
know(125)
know.(262)
least(240)
left(145)
left.emplace(160)
left.end())(154)
left.find(atom);(151)
left.size();(159)
let's(274)
lexeme(229)
like(113)
like:(133)
little(2)
local,(79)
looked(95)
m_ref.by_id;(148)
m_ref.by_word;(146)
made(170)
magically(120)
make(216)
map(6)
mapping(54)
mappings.(36)
maps.(203)
match(212)
mean(234)
meanings,(122)
more(271)
needs(33)
non-space,(238)
not(101)
now,(273)
of(18)
on(185)
only(213)
operator()(Range(138)
or(51)
parameter.(85)
parse(235)
parser(14)
probably(268)
produce(15)
range,(189)
raw(186)
read(70)
reading(243)
redundancy(197)
removes(195)
return(155)
right(147)
right.emplace(iID,(163)
rule(227)
same(199)
semantic(31)
sequence(17)
sidestep(39)
silently)(224)
since(178)
size_t;(47)
skip(222)
skipper(264)
so(239)
some(270)
source(187)
stay(107)
std::map<Atom,(56)
std::map<AtomId,(59)
std::string_view;(49)
steps,(272)
storing(198)
stretches(237)
struct(53)
suggest(106)
sure(217)
synthesized(77)
text)(140)
text.size()};(143)
that(27)
the(5)
them(23)
things(112)
thinking(176)
this(89)
to(7)
treatment(88)
two(202)
type.(10)
unless(233)
use(3)
using(44)
vector,(182)
very(102)
want(13)
was(175)
when(242)
whitespace,(248)
whitespaces(223)
will(28)
without(123)
word(253)
wrap(218)
you(12)
you'll(98)
you've(94)
your(30)
{(55)
}(166)
};(62)
```

Oh I forgot to actually store the `Atoms`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95d98f42f23042ac)</kbd>**

```
Atoms idlist;
if (qi::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), sParser, idlist)) {
    std::cout << "Parsed " << sMapping.by_id.size() << " unique atoms\n";
    for (AtomId id : idlist) {
        std::cout << "'" << sMapping.by_id.at(id) << "' ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
} else {
    // ...
```

Prints something starting like:

```
Parsed 282 unique atoms
'There' 'is' 'little' 'use' 'binding' 'the' 'map' 'to' 'the' 'exposed' 'attribute' 'type.' 'What' 'you' 'want' 'the' ...
```

### BONUS

- Using Boost Bimap instead of handrolling the two maps. This keeps things always in sync and is about 15 lines of code shorter:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2daf04283e15a830)</kbd>**

```
using mapping = boost::bimap<Atom, AtomId>;

// ...

AtomId convert_f::operator()(Range const& text) const {
    Atom atom{&*text.begin(), text.size()};
    return m_ref.left.insert({atom, m_ref.size()}).first->second;
}
```

And then in the usage:

```
std::cout << "Parsed " << sMapping.size() << " unique atoms\n";
for (AtomId id : idlist) {
    std::cout << "'" << sMapping.right.at(id) << "' ";
}
```

Comment: Add a bonus take that uses Boost Bimap instead of handrolling the two maps ([Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2daf04283e15a830)). See "BONUS" section at the bottom. Bonus bonus: [c++11 only version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85e28f4510946ae8)