# lambda not accepted in boost spirit's lazy arguments

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

`eps` accepts a lazy argument that evaluates bool.

I've been using `eps` with pheonix objects like `eps(_r1 == 0) >> something`, and it has worked.

However, when I use a lambda function for more complex expression that can't be expressed in a pheonix form, static assertion is raised and fails to compile.

```
auto test_lazy_arg_f = [](const auto&, const auto& context) {
  return true;
}

boost::spirit::qi::eps(test_lazy_arg_f) >> whatever_i_need;
```

This fails to compile with the following error:

```
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/rule.hpp:177:13: error: static assertion failed: error_invalid_expression
         BOOST_SPIRIT_ASSERT_MATCH(qi::domain, Expr);
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/eiM6zDfyzuapcQtB (Thanks Nikita Kniazev)

I don't see any restriction on lazy arguments in spirit documentations.

How can I use non-pheonix function object?

Comment: It is very interesting that [Lazy Argument](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/basics.html#spirit.qi.reference.basics.lazy_argument) documentation mentions pure functions, but in a reality it never supported that.

Comment: @NikitaKniazev Ah. That matches my experience too. I think it's just copied a little bit too _verbatim_ from the section describing _semantic actions_, which _does_ in many ways evaluate the expressions in a very similar context mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code shown can't reproduce your issue (https://wandbox.org/permlink/uE5ONUXCjuX7j4Mt). I assume you meant in more context.

I think the "raw function signature" only works for exact matches (which are inconvenient to get right and hard to maintain, see [boost spirit semantic action parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066701/boost-spirit-semantic-action-parameters/3067881#3067881)).

So to make any callable object (your polymorphic lambda is such a thing) into a Phoenix actor, use `phoenix::bind`. I personally like to use `phoenix:function<>` to wrap my callable objects.

I have many examples of that, but see e.g. [boost spirit semantic action using non-void function objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082565/boost-spirit-semantic-action-using-non-void-function-objects)

Comment: to hit this assertation you need `parse` call or assign the parser to a rule https://wandbox.org/permlink/eiM6zDfyzuapcQtB

Comment: @NikitaKniazev Thanks. Actual assertation is raised when `parse` is called. I've edited the post.

Comment: @NikitaKniazev I'm aware of that, thanks anyways. In the future, you could add it to the question, I think